# C# MonoTouch/Xamarin.iOS - AVPlayer Streamed Audio Buffer Start Point

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, avplayer

When using an AVPlayer to stream audio from a server - At what point does the player begin loading the audio into itself?

Does it only begin doing this when you click avPlayer.Play() ?

Or does it begin to load the audio immediately at the point of instantiating the AVPlayer with an NSURL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it should begin loading when initialized with an `NSUrl`. You can check the status with `AVPlayer.Status`, which will return `ReadyToPlay` at the appropriate time.